# Настройка ЧПУ для сайта с динамическим меню

Tags: php, .htaccess

Написал меню для сайта(php) в котором все страницы подгружаются через include(), вот код меню:

```
<?php

            switch($_GET['menu']) {

            case 'main':
            include_once("main.php");
            break;

            case 'contacts':
            include_once("contacts.php");
            break;
...
```

выбор идет чере параметр "menu". В итоге получаются ссылки вида http://site/?menu=contacts
Не могу разобраться как сделать чтобы ссылки были вот такого плана http://site/contacts.php.
Ссылки меню выгледят следующим образом

```
<a href="?menu=main">главная</a>
<a href="?menu=contacts">контакты</a>
```

Comment: используйте `mod rewrite`

Comment: в данный момент пытаюсь разобраться, не могли бы вы мне немного помочь в данном вопросе?

Comment: попробовал прописать в .htaccess следующее правило RewriteRule ?menu=(.*)$ $1.php

Comment: RewriteRule (.*).php$ index.php?menu=$1

Comment: а как заменить передачу параметра в ссылках меню - <a href="?menu=contacts"> ?

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess пишеш:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?menu=$1 [QSA,L]
```