# Отправить параметр методом GET и преобразовать его в ЧПУ

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Меню сайта

```
<a href="?menu=main">главная</a>
<a href="?menu=contacts">контакты</a>
```

Подключение нужной страницы

```
<?php

            switch($_GET['menu']) {

            case 'main':
            include_once("main.php");
            break;

            case 'contacts':
            include_once("contacts.php");
            break;
...
```

На главной странице методом Switch через include() подключается нужная страница.
В итоге ссылка имеет вид http://site/?menu=contacts, а нужно чтобы было  http://site/contacts Насколько я понимаю нужно изменить ссылки в меню чтобы в дальнейшем их можно было преобразовать с помощью mod_rewrite?

Comment: Кто вам запрещает писать в меню вместо `<a href="?menu=contacts">контакты</a>` так `<a href="http://site/contacts">контакты</a>`?

Comment: Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644257/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%a7%d0%9f%d0%a3-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8e

Comment: если я буду использовать такую ссылку  <a href="http://site/contacts">контакты</a> то как я передам  GET параметр, который подключит инклюдом нужную страницу?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542869/186083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В твоем конкретно случае выполни следующие шаги: 
1) Создай файл .htaccess в той директории где у тебя лежит главный файл index.php, на который идут все запросы. Содержание .htaccess следующее

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Теперь если ты сделаешь запрос например такой: [http://site/contacts/еще_что_то/и_еще/и_так_далее](http://site/contacts/%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE_%D1%82%D0%BE/%D0%B8_%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5/%D0%B8_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5), то в файл index.php ты получаешь $_GET['url'] в котором содержится строка 'contacts/еще_что_то/и_еще/и_так_далее'. Возможно понадобится включить mod_rewrite в php.ini файле сервера - если он отключен
2) Пишешь функцию парсер, которая будет разбивать полученный url на состовляющие

```
function parseUrl()
{
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
        return $url = explode('/', urldecode(filter_var(urlencode(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/')), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)));
    }
}
```

3) Вызываешь в index.php эту функцию. Получаешь массив. Первым ключём будет идти имя файла. Далее по желанию: в файле допустим класс с таким же именем как имя файла и в нем есть метод который ты хочешь с лету вызвать - не проблема - имя метода будет у тебя во втором элементе массива к примеру, остальные элементы это например какие то дополнительные get параметры. В целом как то так будет выглядеть. Можешь упростить и выбросить что не нужно

```
$url = parseUrl();
$controller = '';
if (file_exists($url[0] . '.php')) {
    $controller = $url[0];
    unset($url[0]);
}
//тут подключается нужный файл. Если например запрос http://site/contacts 
//то подключится contacts.php
require_once $controller . '.php';
//Все что дальше не обязательно, если в файле $controller есть класс 
//с таким же именем как имя файла, то можно на лету создать объект 
//этого класса вот так
$class = new $controller();
//далее если запрос например вот такой http://site/contacts/addNewContact
//то в $url[1] будет имя метода класса - сохраняем чтобы чуть ниже вызвать. 
$action = '';
if (isset($url[1])) {
    if (method_exists($controller, $url[1])) {
        $action = $url[1];
        unset($url[1]);
    }
}
//в этом месте в массиве url остаются только дополнительные параметры
//если вдруг ты сделал запрос http://site/contacts/removeContacts/3/4
//эти параметры можно передать в метод класса - как массив array(3,4)
$params = $url ? array_values($url) : array();
//вызываем метод который запомнили ранее и передаем параметры
call_user_func(array($controller, $action), $params);
```

Comment: огромное тебе спасибо за помощь! очень подробно описано! еще раз спасибо!